# Need assistance with my OO design

Tags: oop, class

Here is the scenario.

```
public interface Processor{

    public void create();

    public void setDocuments();

    public abstract void prepareDocuments();

}

public class ProcessorImpl implements Processor{

    public void create(){
        // Do something
    }

    public void setDocuments(){
       // Do something
    }

}

public class ProcessorA implements ProcessorImpl{
    // this class will implement only once abstract 
    // method which is prepareDocuments()

    public void prepareDocuments(){
       // prepare documents..and also 
       // set the Documents list which will be checked by create() 
       // method and then index will be created.

    }

}


public class IndexGenerator{

    public static void main( String[] args){

       ProcessorA a = new ProcessorAImpl();
       a.create();  
    }
}
```

Brief background....I am developing a generic framework to handle all Lucene index related activities which includes create index, delete doc from index, update and add into index. All the logic to handle the index remains same except creating documents. Each index have different type of Document therefore I have kept prepareDocuments() method abstract and have it implemented for each index type.

Now I want to have all the index generator classes simply create an instance of their specific index Processor like ProcessorA and invoke create() method. But the problem is that create() methods always finds documents list empty / null although prepareDocuments is setting the documents by calling setDocuments() method. I know there is some design flaw which I really need to seek help form OO gurus.

Thanks
Zealous

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you get empty/null, because there is not enough code from which we can deduce it. However, for your problem I would go with **Template method** design pattern, decsribed for example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

I think thats even what you are trying to do.

Btw. `implements` keyword is used only for interfaces. You try to use it instead of `extends` here:

```
public class ProcessorA implements ProcessorImpl
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the previous answer (that I agree with completely) regarding Templates, it sounds like you may have a problem with the order in which setDocuments() is being called. One of the benefits of the Template Method Pattern is to force the order in which the different methods (abstract or not) are called.

You may consider restructuring the base-class like this:

```
public interface Processor {
    ...
    // This method orchestrates doc preparation by ensuring the correct
    // ordering of method invocation, and calls the derived class impl
    // method doPrepareDocuments()
    public void prepareDocuments() {
        // do document creation stuff here by calling
        // appropriate methods (abstract or not)

        setDocuments();

        // implemented in derived classes to do specific document preparations
        doPrepareDocuments();
    }

    public abstract void doPrepareDocuments();
    ...
}
```

This way every derived class implementation doesnt have to remember all of the steps to be taken, and and in what order, but instead focuses on what it knows. This approach increases  Cohesion.